# What means the undefined “url” property in “IncomingMessage” of “http” module?

Tags: node.js, http

According TypeScript types definitions, the "IncomingMessage.url" could be `undefined`:

```js
class IncomingMessage extends stream.Readable {
  // ...
  url?: string | undefined;
}
```

What the `undefined` value tells to us and how me should handle this value?

Currently I do it as below:

```js
import HTTP from "http";
import {
  HTTP_StatusCodes,
  Logger,
  isUndefined,
  UnsupportedScenarioError
} from "@yamato-daiwa/es-extensions";


class Server {

  private async requestMasterListener(
    request: HTTP.IncomingMessage,
    rawResponse: HTTP.ServerResponse,
    loggingData: {
      port: number;
      protocol: string;
    }
  ): Promise<void> {

    // ...

    if (isUndefined(request.url)) {
      Logger.logError({
        errorType: UnsupportedScenarioError.NAME,
        title: UnsupportedScenarioError.DEFAULT_TITLE,
        description: "The request URL is not defined.",
        occurrenceLocation: "Server.requestMasterListener(request, rawResponse)"
      });
      rawResponse.
          writeHead(HTTP_StatusCodes.badRequest, "The request URL is undefined").
          end();
      return;
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: There could easily be a whole subcategory of questions on StackOverflow, such as "Why is _a thing_ typed in this way in TypeScript?"

Answer (score 1):

From the comments inside [http.d.ts](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/94472a5/types/node/http.d.ts):

Class docs:

> An `IncomingMessage` object is created by {@link Server} or {@link ClientRequest}

`url` docs:

> **Only valid for request obtained from {@link Server}.**

So, there is no `url` along other methods if created from `ClientRequest`. Probably, it would be a good idea to make typings more sensitive to this differences.